# LAN or Ethernet on RPI3 not working completely

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, internet, dhcp, static-ip

My network uses static IP distrobution instead of DHCP or dynamic. So, I plugged PI 3 on the network and updated the **INTERFACES** file as below.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
static ip_address=192.168.1.3
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

This works partially. My PI 3 is able to ping any computers connected to my network, but when I tell it go out on the Internet it fails.

I don't know why this is.

Comment: You need to assign a gateway to the external network.

Comment: Can it resolve the hostname? What error message does it return?

Comment: Also: Simply assigning yourself an IP does not mean the router will automatically forward traffic from it, so if you have not arranged that with on the router nothing you do on the Pi will change it.

Comment: I have set up a range of allowed IP addresses on my router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your `netmask` and your `gateway`.

add:

```
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

...assuming those are correct for your network.